# How can I insert an unordered list inside a note in Asciidoc without losing the note?

Tags: documentation, asciidoc, asciidoctor

How to add an unordered list inside a note in Asciidoc?
I tried the following syntax but the Note disappears and the unordered list appears without being enclosed in a note.
Is there a workaround to insert a list into a note?

The syntax I tried :

```
[NOTE]
* The *ID* and *Status* fields are *non-editable in Scope, Profile and Users* while the *Username is also non-editable in Users*,one can only edit the other values. 
* The *Apply button is initially disabled* prior to making any changes.
* If you try to perform other actions before applying the changes made, the following pop-up appears.
```

Answer (score 1):

With [admonition block syntax](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/blocks/admonitions/#admonition-syntax) the content is typically delimited by four equal signs (====).

For example:

```
[NOTE]
====
* Foo
* Bar
* Baz
====
```